# Como ejecuto otra función con http request

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una función que contiene un http request y pues necesito y pues esa función es la que me crea mi html con la data que traigo y lo que quiero es que en otra función a través de http request también y usando un onclick me ejecute mi consulta pues lo hice con jquery pero me lo solicitaron con http request. les dejo mi código que hace el html

```js
function inactiva(){
  var inactive = new XMLHttpRequest();
  inactive.open("POST",url_inactive,true);
  inactive.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  inactive.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if ( inactive.readyState == 4 && inactive.status == 200 ) {
      var inact = JSON.parse(inactive.response);
          inact = inact['sections_inactive'];
      console.log(inact);
      console.log(inact.length);

      if ( inact.length > 0 ) {
        inactivas.innerHTML = "Inactivas";

        for (i = 0; i < inact.length; i++) {
          var id = inact[i]['id_section'];
          var namesection = inact[i]['name_section'];

          resultado2.innerHTML += '<div class="block"><a onclick="activar()" class="desactivado" id="'+ id +'" data-id="'+ id +'" href="">' + namesection + '</a></div>';
        }
      } else {
        resultado2.innerHTML = '<div class="block"><p>No tienes secciones activas</p></div>';
      }
    }
  }
  inactive.send();
}
```

Y este es el código que estuve intentando hacer para poder ejecutar mi consulta y la acción

```js
function acitvar(){
  var clickactive = new XMLHttpRequest();
  clickactive.open("POST",urlclickactive,true);
  clickactive.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  clickactive.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if ( clickactive.readyState == 4 && clickactive.status == 200 ) {
      resultado.innerHTML += clickactive.responseText;
    }
  }
  clickactive.send();
}
```

Comment: El nombre de tu funcion tiene un typo.

Comment: @alanfcm que funcion?

Comment: Solo muestras dos funciones.  Una de las dos esta mal escrita.

Comment: mejor dime como puedo mandar una variable por httprequest y pues esa variable es la data-id que esta en la primera funcion que genera un html